# Trim leading and trailing white spaces in JSON values

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

All,

I make a JSON request to a web server using PHP and it returns me a JSON response in a variable. The JSON response will have lots of keys and values. I would like a function which trims leading and trailing white spaces in each "value" of the key-value pair for the entire JSON response.

How can I do that through PHP?

Ex: json_decode breaks due to trailing spaces or special characters:

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
  "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
   "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
     "SortAs": "SGML",
     "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language‡ﬂﬁ·€..  ",
     "Acronym": "SGML",
     "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
     "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "create markup languages such as DocBook.     ",
      "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
     "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `json_decode` does not break on this string.

Answer (score 2):

Process the data BEFORE it's encoded into JSON format. Better to clean up the source than mess with the JSON version and possibly break the syntax with a malformed regex deleting something it shouldn't have.

Basically, do this:

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = trim($value);
}

$json = json_encode($data);  // $json's values are now pre/post-whitespace free
```

(assuming it's a simple 1-dimensional array).

edit/comment followup:

Is your PHP script fetching this external JSON? If that's the case, then you can trivially decode the JSON into a PHP object/array, do the whitespace trimming, and re-encode into JSON:

```
$json = get_json_from_external_source();
$data = json_decode($json);
```

and then the foreach loop (or array_map as mentioned in Tomalak's comment) as before. If you're limited to doing this client-side in Javascript, then you can do the equivalent processing there before handing the data over to whatever function requires it.

edit/comment followup #2:

I highly doubt it's the trailing spaces inside the JSON data's values. JSON is perfectly capable of handling spaces wherever they occur within a string and doesn't care how many (or few) there are. Most likely it's the funky characters in the `GlossTerm` entry.

If you're on PHP 5.3 (or a higher beta version), there's [`json_last_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) which will report as to why the decode's failing.

Comment: I guess `$data = array_map("trim", $data)` would do it as well.

Comment: The issue is, I get the json response from an external source. I don't generate it. Hence need to trim the spaces in the response, before i dcode it to array format

Comment: @Marc: I believe that in my code due to the trailing spaces in the external json, the json_decode() function is failing for me. Any suggestions on cleaning up the JSON before the json_decode?

Comment: @Vincent: Can you post an example of your broken JSON input?

Comment: @Vincent: The JSON Validator (http://www.jsonlint.com/) thinks it is valid JSON. Looks like you need to post the failing PHP code, also. Please make a fully functional, reproducibly failing code sample.