# preg_replace and possible json issues

Tags: php

I need to replace a whitespace at the beginning of any newline. I am using JSON to send over the POST values and suspect this may have something to do with it not working.

```
$str='
This is a string.
   This should be left justified by removing whitespaces preceding it.
';
preg_replace('/^\s+/', '', $str);
```

Running this, works as expected. When I attempt to use it with my POST array, the whitespaces remain. Why?

Does JSON play a part in this?

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, the array being sent over is not JSON encoded, it is a PHP array using JSON POST.

I just tried modifying my regex a bit and can at least verify that preg_replace is doing *something*. If I do: `/\s+/`, all spaces are removed. So, I know it's working somewhat.

Is my regex correct?

**EDIT #2**

This is making me crazy. I figured I would just trim the whitespace in my javascript and call it a day, but I'm getting the same exact result.

Is there any other circumstance that would stop this regex from matching?

`/^\s+/`

Comment: No.. Good thinking though. I am doing this: `$str=preg_replace('/^\s+/', '', $_POST['myValue']);` and then calling `$str` where I need it.

Comment: `ltrim()`? ...............

Comment: Hmm. I'm willing to try and use this if it works. Thanks. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @Deadooshka, nope. :(  I get the same thing, whitespaces.

Comment: this means `$str` may contain encoded spaces. `&nbsp;`, `%20` etc.

Comment: @Deadooshka, Wait, did you want me to try `ltrim` with my preg_replace? I removed the preg_replace and just tried `ltrim`

Comment: both `preg_replace` and `ltrim` must give same result without spaces.

Comment: @Deadooshka, There are no HTML entities in the string anywhere. I've checked at least 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
$str='
This is a string.
   This should be left justified by removing whitespaces preceding it.
';
preg_replace('/^\s+/m', '', $str);
```

I've just added the `m` modifier. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: OK, what that does do is removes all the return and newline characters from the string, effectively putting everything on a single line.

Comment: Not in a test script, it doesn't. In other words, if I just put your code into a php file and execute `php thefile.php` on the command line, I get the expected result. So maybe you're losing newlines some other way.

Comment: That's why I was suspecting that JSON may play a role in this. It's just a simple POST and then in my PHP script, I run it through preg_replace. I know, it's really weird. I agree, if JSON isn't involved, it renders as expected.

Comment: Maybe your real problem is nothing to do with preg_replace, then. Ie, the answer to your question is that there is nothing much wrong with your regex. Do some things like `var_dump ($_POST['myValue']);` before replacement, then `var_dump ($str);` afterwards. Also, to be certain about what is being sent (including encoded line endings etc), look at the POST information in the html headers via your browser's dev tools.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll have a look and see what I can find. If nobody else answers this question, I'll be back to accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Chris, I have done a var_dump before and afterwards and see the exact same result. The whitespace characters are still there, before and after. I figured I would just use regex in the javascript and be done with it but I'm also getting the same exact result. That certainly rules out anything in my PHP. I just don't know where to go from here.

Comment: My other suggestion was to look at what was being sent in the POST header. Without that info, my only guess is that you have non-breaking spaces in your string. Try this: `$str=preg_replace('/\xA0/u',' ',$str); $str=preg_replace('/^\s+/m', '', $str);`

Comment: Chris, I've looked at the headers and forgot to tell you what I found. The page is encoded in utf-8. I can also post them if need be. Regarding your last suggestion, I tried both preg_replace functions and it will left justify the text. This is more than I was getting before, so that's good. It is removing the newline, which I don't want. I need any newlines to remain intact. Would this be acceptable: `preg_replace('/^\s+/m', "\n", $str);`? Can you please explain the first preg_replace regex? I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: @NaN `m`-flag mean multiline pattern and useless in this case. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php . If the string contain the BOM, so firstly remove the BOM. Google "PHP remove BOM"

Comment: The first part removes non-breaking spaces (A0 in unicode). The u flag means treat the string as unicode. The \x means what follows is a unicode encoding.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach($trim_val as $key => $value) {
    $trim_val[$key] = trim($value);
}
$json = json_encode($trim_val);
```

already solution is here given by someone, [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399030/trim-leading-and-trailing-white-spaces-in-json-values)